# Does tr contrain specific class Ruby Nokogiri

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to identify `tr` tags with class `favoured` such as:

```
<tr class="home favoured ">
```

I have this:

```
tableSpread = doc.css('.consensus-table').first
tableSpread.search('tr').each do |tr|
    tr.at_css('.favoured')
end
```

I'm having no success identifying the class; I'm getting `nil` for every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tr` is the same node that has class `favoured`, whereas your use of the selectors is valid when you want to match a descendant of `tr` that has class `favoured`. You should do:

```
tableSpread.search('tr.favoured').each do |tr|
  ...
end
```

Comment: You can also test whether a node has a class using `tr.matches?('.favoured')`, if you need more complex conditional processing; but if you just want to "identify `tr` tags with class `favoured`", sawa's is a much better choice.